# Sonar rule to be validate logging framework

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j, sonarqube

I have to use only slf4j framework in my project instead of log4j. Is there any way to set custom sonar rule to validation logging framework and to show violation if we use log4j.

Of course we can use logj-over-slf4j to avoid compilation errors. But I need to use strictly slf4j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. (I am assuming you are using Java, correct?)

You can activate the [IllegalImport](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#IllegalImport) check from the Checkstyle repository in your Java quality profile. Make sure to add `org.apache.log4j` to the list of `illegalPkgs`. E.g. set `illegalPkgs` to `sun, com.sun, org.apache.log4j`.

Also, in SonarQube, you can activate the [Architectural Constraint](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Architecture+Rule+Engine) rule. Here, you must set the `toClasses` property to a wildcard expression such as `org.apache.log4j.**`.